# Add description for my app when choosing the app to open a file in Windows File Explorer

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How to display an overview of my application (small description) when opening app selection to choose the app that will open some file in Windows File Explorer.
To access this scenario, just open the file explorer, choose an image, for example, and: click the right button > open with > choose another app.

I wish the description to match this attached image:
[image: image showing app description in windows 10]

Comment: I don't think that Windows has allowed that for third party applications. I've never seen descriptions for anything other than Microsoft applications, so it's not possible (if it was possible, you'd see _someone_ do it).

Comment: It would be a nice feature for our apps. Thanks!